# ASP.NET request validation causes: is there a list?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

is anybody aware of a list of exactly what triggers ASP.NET's HttpRequestValidationException? [This is behind the common error: "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected," etc.]

I've checked here, around the Web, and MSDN Library but can't find this documented. I'm aware of some ways to generate the error, but would like to have a complete list so I can guard against and selectively circumvent it (I know how to disable request validation for a page, but this isn't an option in this case).

Is it a case of "security through obscurity"?

Thanks.

[Note: Scripts won't load for me in IE8 (as described frequently in the Meta forum) so I won't be able to "Add comment."]

EDIT 1: Hi Oded, are you aware of a list that documents the conditions used to determine a "potentially malicious input string"? That's what I'm looking for.

EDIT 2: @Chris Pebble: Yeah, what you said. :)

Comment: +1 There appears to be a dearth of information regarding this error. Finding a list of everything RequestValidation protects from would be very useful.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately we can't just read the source code. Hopefully somebody who reads this knows or can find out.

[Finally got them to install Firefox for me so I can comment--not admin on my machine.]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I couldn't find a document outlining a conclusive list, but looking through Reflector and doing some analysis on use of HttpRequestValidationException, it looks like validation errors on the following can cause the request validation to fail:

- A filename in one of the files POSTed to an upload.
- The incoming request raw URL.
- The value portion of the name/value pair from any of the incoming cookies.
- The value portion of the name/value pair from any of the fields coming in through GET/POST.

The question, then, is "what qualifies one of these things as a dangerous input?" That seems to happen during an internal method System.Web.CrossSiteScriptingValidation.IsDangerousString(string, out int) which looks like it decides this way:

1. Look for `<` or `&` in the value. If it's not there, or if it's the last character in the value, then the value is OK.
2. If the `&` character is in a `&#` sequence (e.g., `&#160;` for a non-breaking space), it's a "dangerous string."
3. If the `<` character is part of `<x` (where "x" is any alphabetic character a-z), `<!`, `</`, or `<?`, it's a "dangerous string."
4. Failing all of that, the value is OK.

The System.Web.CrossSiteScriptingValidation type seems to have other methods in it for determining if things are dangerous URLs or valid JavaScript IDs, but those don't appear, at least through Reflector analysis, to result in throwing HttpRequestValidationExceptions.

Comment: Thanks Travis--I'm reviewing your list along with the code The Matt listed below. [Can't I mark them both as answers? ;)]

So it seems like it's basically '<(alpha)+' and '&#' it's concerned about, and this matches my testing.

Answer (score 17):

## Update:

**Warning:** Some parts of the code in the original answer (below) were removed and marked as OBSOLETE.

#### Latest source code in Microsoft site (has syntax highlighting):

> http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/CrossSiteScriptingValidation.cs

After checking the newest code you will probably agree that what [Travis Illig explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2233249/146513) are the only validations used now in 2018 (and seems to have no changes since 2014 when the source was released [in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/CrossSiteScriptingValidation.cs)). But the old code below may still be relevant if you use an older version of the framework.

---

## Original Answer:

Using Reflector, I did some browsing. Here's the raw code. When I have time I will translate this into some meaningful rules:

The `HttpRequestValidationException` is thrown by only a single method in the `System.Web` namespace, so it's rather isolated. Here is the method:

```
private void ValidateString(string s, string valueName, string collectionName)
{
    int matchIndex = 0;
    if (CrossSiteScriptingValidation.IsDangerousString(s, out matchIndex))
    {
        string str = valueName + "=\"";
        int startIndex = matchIndex - 10;
        if (startIndex <= 0)
        {
            startIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            str = str + "...";
        }
        int length = matchIndex + 20;
        if (length >= s.Length)
        {
            length = s.Length;
            str = str + s.Substring(startIndex, length - startIndex) + "\"";
        }
        else
        {
            str = str + s.Substring(startIndex, length - startIndex) + "...\"";
        }
        throw new HttpRequestValidationException(HttpRuntime.FormatResourceString("Dangerous_input_detected", collectionName, str));
    }
}
```

That method above makes a call to the `IsDangerousString` method in the `CrossSiteScriptingValidation` class, which validates the string against a series of rules. It looks like the following:

```
internal static bool IsDangerousString(string s, out int matchIndex)
{
    matchIndex = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        int index = s.IndexOfAny(startingChars, startIndex);
        if (index < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (index == (s.Length - 1))
        {
            return false;
        }
        matchIndex = index;
        switch (s[index])
        {
            case 'E':
            case 'e':
                if (IsDangerousExpressionString(s, index))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                break;

            case 'O':
            case 'o':
                if (!IsDangerousOnString(s, index))
                {
                    break;
                }
                return true;

            case '&':
                if (s[index + 1] != '#')
                {
                    break;
                }
                return true;

            case '<':
                if (!IsAtoZ(s[index + 1]) && (s[index + 1] != '!'))
                {
                    break;
                }
                return true;

            case 'S':
            case 's':
                if (!IsDangerousScriptString(s, index))
                {
                    break;
                }
                return true;
        }
        startIndex = index + 1;
    }
}
```

That `IsDangerousString` method appears to be referencing a series of validation rules, which are outlined below:

```
private static bool IsDangerousExpressionString(string s, int index)
{
    if ((index + 10) >= s.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ((s[index + 1] != 'x') && (s[index + 1] != 'X'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return (string.Compare(s, index + 2, "pression(", 0, 9, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0);
}
```

-

```
private static bool IsDangerousOnString(string s, int index)
{
    if ((s[index + 1] != 'n') && (s[index + 1] != 'N'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ((index > 0) && IsAtoZ(s[index - 1]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    int length = s.Length;
    index += 2;
    while ((index < length) && IsAtoZ(s[index]))
    {
        index++;
    }
    while ((index < length) && char.IsWhiteSpace(s[index]))
    {
        index++;
    }
    return ((index < length) && (s[index] == '='));
}
```

-

```
private static bool IsAtoZ(char c)
{
    return (((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) || ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')));
}
```

-

```
private static bool IsDangerousScriptString(string s, int index)
{
    int length = s.Length;
    if ((index + 6) >= length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ((((s[index + 1] != 'c') && (s[index + 1] != 'C')) || ((s[index + 2] != 'r') && (s[index + 2] != 'R'))) || ((((s[index + 3] != 'i') && (s[index + 3] != 'I')) || ((s[index + 4] != 'p') && (s[index + 4] != 'P'))) || ((s[index + 5] != 't') && (s[index + 5] != 'T'))))
    {
        return false;
    }
    index += 6;
    while ((index < length) && char.IsWhiteSpace(s[index]))
    {
        index++;
    }
    return ((index < length) && (s[index] == ':'));
}
```

So there you have it. It's not pretty to decipher, but it's all there.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Matt--good call on using Reflector. I'm looking over your response along with Travis' to get a handle on this--basically it seems to be two scenarios that we need to be concerned with (left angle bracket w/ alpha char and ampersand w/ number sign).

Answer (score 2):

How about this script? Your code can not detect this script, right?

```
";}alert(1);function%20a(){//
```

Comment: True.I faced one situation like this where the script is injected like this and it got rendered in a commented line of javascript via RAZOR token.The commented js contained a RAZOR token

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expresson pattern.

You may need to ecape the \ for javascript ex \\

```
var regExpPattern = '[eE][xX][pP][rR][eE][sS][sS][iI][oO][nN]\\(|\\b[oO][nN][a-zA-Z]*\\b\\s*=|&#|<[!/a-zA-Z]|[sS][cC][rR][iI][pP][tT]\\s*:';
var re = new RegExp("","gi");
re.compile(regExpPattern,"gi");
var outString = null;
outString = re.exec(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Travis' answer, the list of 'dangerous' character sequences can be simplified as follows;

- &#
- <A through to <Z (upper and lower case)
- <!
- </
- <?

Based on this, in an ASP.Net MVC web app the following Regex validation attribute can be used on a model field to trigger client side validation before an [HttpRequestValidationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException?view=netframework-4.6.1) is thrown when the form is submitted;

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?![\s\S]*(&#|<[a-zA-Z!\/?]))[\s\S]*$", ErrorMessage = "This field does not support HTML or allow any of the following character sequences; &quot;&amp;#&quot;, &quot;&lt;A&quot; through to &quot;&lt;Z&quot; (upper and lower case), &quot;&lt;!&quot;, &quot;&lt;/&quot; or &quot;&lt;?&quot;.")]
```

Note that validation attribute error messages are HTML encoded when output by server side validation, but not when used in client side validation, so this one is already encoded as we only intend to see it with client side validation.

Answer (score -1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestvalidationexception.aspx):

'The exception that is thrown when a potentially malicious input string is received from the client as part of the request data. '

Many times this happens when JavaScript changes the values of a server side control in a way that causes the ViewState to not agree with the posted data.

Comment: True, but I think the OP was looking for a list characters or combination of characters that would trigger this. He likely knows <html> tags will trigger this error but there are a bunch of other subtle ways to trigger it as well, which is why I believe he's looking for a complete list of all triggers.