# Full list of XSS triggers for ValidateRequest in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security, validation, exception, request

I understand why the exception " “A potentially dangerous Request.Form value…” occurs and why it's useful. I would like to put client-side validators on my page that check if the input contains < > ON= or whatever else may trigger this exception. The problem is, I don't know all the characters or strings that trigger the exception. Is there a list of the triggers some where? I can't seem to find it, only questions/answers relating to the exception itself and how to handle it.

Also, should a request come from an external source, not my form, how can I tell and how can I handle it? Does Asp.NET do this automatically? Would a hidden field work or can hackers get around that?

An information you can give (including links) is appreciated.

UPDATE:

For anyone interested, I came up with a regex that will match any string with these characters.

```
(^((?=.*&#).*)$)|(^((?=.*<).*)$)|(^((?=.*>).*)$)
```

However, when you submit a form, even fields that are in a separate validation group than the button clicked are passed to the server and if any invalid text is in those fields, you get the exception. So, I decided to use an Ajax FilteredTextBoxExtender to block those chars from TextBoxes. Another alternative would be to use a JavaScript keyup function on all the TextBoxes. However, the smart user can disable the JavaScript of both of these and they are not completely reliable.

Comment: Even if You validate on client side You still have to validate it on server side. But I'm not sure what You wan't to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a duplicate of a similar question on this site.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200788/asp-net-request-validation-causes-is-there-a-list) has several answers where people have reflected through the code to get the actual triggers.

In answer to your other question, if invalid input comes in from a request originating somewhere that you don't explicitly validate, for example another site, it will hit ValidateRequest on the server side of your code and the caller will see a 500 error or your custom error page, if enabled.  That's assuming that you allow requests from other servers (read about [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)).  If you don't want to allow requests from other servers you can check the referer of the request and only allow requests from your own site.

Comment: Thank you. I did not see the other question on here, but it breaks it down nicely. :)